# Stop a macro working if the activecell.row is less than a certain number

Tags: vba, excel

I need the following code to work as it doesn't presently, any help would be greatly appreciated
I have been trying for ages with a few variants but just can't seem to get it to work

```
Sub INCOMENEWLINE()
'
' INCOMENEWLINE Macro
'

'
If ActiveCell.Row < 74 Then
    MsgBox "You cannot insert a new line here"
    Exit Sub
End If

If ActiveCell.Row > 73 Then
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="PB2014"
    Range("SAFILTER").AutoFilter
    Range("INCOMENEWLINE").Copy
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert
    Selection.RowHeight = 13.5
    Range("SAFILTER").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="O"
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Range("I5:J5")
        c.EntireColumn.Hidden = (c.Value = 0)
    Next c
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
        , Password:="PB2014"
    Exit Sub
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: what is it supposed to achieve? have you tried debugging and stepping through? what does not work as expected?

Comment: I want to insert a specific 2 lines named INCOMENEWLINE in to a worksheet but don't want people to be able to insert these lines above row 73 as there are headers and calculations at the top of the worksheet that I don't want people to be able to insert between as this worksheet feeds in to another workbook and if the rows change before row 73 it will send the wrong information in to the linked file

Comment: I don't want to put the calculations in a separate worksheet in the same workbook to then feed through either (which I appreciate would be a workaround but won't work in this case for other reasons)

Comment: At present I select a cell after row 73 and press the macro button to run this macro and it does nothing - so i don't really have anything to debug

Comment: If I select a row above row 73 then I don't get the pop up message box either so I'm very confused

Comment: Put a MsgBox outside of the `If` tests - does that run?

Comment: Not sure what you mean could you show me in the code please @TimWilliams

Comment: Also for @mehow the main chunk of code in the second if function works in isolation

Comment: Solved it :)Sub INCOMENEWLINE()
If ActiveCell.Row < 74 Then
MsgBox "You cannot insert a new line here"
Else
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="PB2014"
Range("SAFILTER").AutoFilter
    Range("INCOMENEWLINE").Copy
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert
    Selection.RowHeight = 13.5
    Range("SAFILTER").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="O"
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Range("I5:J5")
        c.EntireColumn.Hidden = (c.Value = 0)
    Next c
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
        , Password:="PB2014"
End If
End Sub

Comment: Better to update your question with the revised code, or post as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code in VBAProject->Microsoft Excel Objects->Sheet1(Sheet1) or whatever sheet you'd like.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If ActiveCell.Row < 74 Then
        MsgBox "You cannot insert a new line here"
    Else
        'Insert the rest of your code here
    End If
End Sub
```

It'll automatically run whenever you selection changes. So yeah, put that in your Sheet code, not a module or user form.

You might have to separate he macros into something like this too:

Declare public variable:

```
Public StopMacro as Boolean
```

Then have this:

```
Sub SetStopMacro()

StopMacro = True

End Sub
```

And finally:

```
Sub Macro1()
    While StopMacro is not False
        ''Do Stuff
        ''Do more stuff
        Exit sub ''This is if you don't want this code running over and over again
    Wend
End Sub
```

And then you would call SetStopMacro in the Worksheet_SelectionChange sub.

Answer (score 0):

try to change activecell.row to selection.row